# Is there any way to enable a screen keyboard when input is required?

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, touchscreen

I just upgraded from Freya to Loki and realised that it has touchscreen support! Which made me happy since it works perfectly. The only problem is that when I have to type something I have to use the physical keyboard. Is there any way to enable a screen keyboard that shows up when an input is required, just like Windows do?

Answer (score 4):

System Settings > Universal Access > Typing > On-screen keyboard

More advanced settings like hiding it when not in use and layout are available when you click on "On-screen keyboard settings..."

Comment: Any way to make it show up only when I am using the touchscreen like in Windows? I checked the option "Auto-show when editing text" but if I am using the mouse I am not interested on it...